# Android Ellipsize left

Tags: android, textview

Is there any way to Ellipsize on the left side? Eg 123456790 becomes ...56790

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess **android:ellipsize="start"** should do that:

```
<TextView android:ellipsize="start" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="123456790"/>
```

Comment: It never occurred to meet that it would be that simple